# tinyproxy with user authentication

Tags: authentication, pam, http-proxy

Does anybody have a solution that'll make [tinyproxy](https://banu.com/tinyproxy/) work with user authentication like `pam_auth` at the squid proxy?

I don't want to create a SSH-Tunnel and allow only localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In searching through the project's website and in grepping through the source tree for tinyproxy I see no mentions of pam anywhere.

For the first I searched through the site using Google's `site:..` facility searching for the string "pam".

For the source tree I downloaded it using `git`:

```
$ git clone git://git.banu.com/tinyproxy.git
$ grep -ri pam tinyproxy
$
```

In looking through the website they look to manage the project in a very typical Open Source manner so you might want to pose your question on one of the mailing lists or use IRC to ask.

Let me know and I can help if you're interested in following up either of these 2 leads.

#### UPDATE #1

To help facilitate this I've created a bug in tinyproxy's issue tracker.

- [Does tinyproxy support authentication through pam modules?](https://bugzilla.banu.com/show_bug.cgi?id=118)

Comment: @JohnSmithv1 - not sure if you know this but you can also upvote + accept. Don't feel obligated, but just making you aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

a 2018 release now has basic http AUTH support, find on github https://github.com/tinyproxy/tinyproxy/releases